# Stealth address transaction example on Bitcoin's blockchain

Tags: stealth-address

I am looking for an example transaction on Bitcoin's blockchain using stealth addressing.

I am brainstorming how stealth addresses would be used amongst normal addresses in combination (whereas [Monero](http://monero.cc/) and [CryptoNote](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CryptoNote) protocols so far only use stealth addresses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot tell them apart from transactions using ordinary addresses; they are exactly the same.  Any regular transaction you look at could have been created using a stealth address.

As I wrote in my answer [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29648/5757), a "stealth address" is just one particular way of generating a unique address, known only to the payer and payee, to use for a transaction.  Once the unique address is created, the transaction itself is created just like any other.