# Dark wallet stealth address

Tags: bitcoin-core, stealth-address

Please can anyone recover my coins from a dark wallet stealth address, how do i go about recovering the private key?? i have the seed but i don't know what derivation path the stealth addresses are stored, please help me

Comment: What software did you use to generate the address?

Comment: Looks like Dark wallet is the software in question: https://www.darkwallet.is/. I'm not sure how their stealth addresses work, however

Answer (score 1):

Dark wallet (https://github.com/darkwallet) is essentially inactive and was alphaware, never meant to be used for production use. It was a grand experiment. Its architectural integration vision with libbitcoin is shown here at [**this**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin.github.io/blob/master/libbitcoin-roadmap.pdf) deprecated webpage.

Take a look at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/what-is-a-stealth-address/1506#1506 to understand what a stealth address really is.  Funds sent to a stealth address will require scanning a blockchain for appropriate **OP_RETURN** address to complete Diffie-Hellman key exchages to calculate private keys. There will be different private keys for each transaction sent using a wallet that supports stealth transactions. The libbitcoin-server (bs) indexes stealth transactions, see https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-server/wiki/How-to-Initialize. The libbitcoin-explorer (bx) also supports bs stealth interactions, see https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/Stealth-Commands. Good luck.

Comment: Update - see https://samouraiwallet.com/features.html supports BIP 39. If the Darkwallet used BIP 39 keys for configuration, you try loading those Darkwallet BIP 39 keys if the into a Samouraiwallet. Also see this dated URL: http://www.openbitcoinprivacyproject.org/stealth-address-tracker/.

Answer (score 0):

> **i don't know what derivation path the stealth addresses are stored**

According to [bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/DarkWallet)

> The project gained significant media attention for its use of modern [BIP 0032](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032) wallet format

You can obtain the Javascript source code from [sourceforge](https://github.com/darkwallet/darkwallet)

> We're still in alpha state, that means we're still changing things a lot and **it's not safe at all to use the wallet**.  ...
>
> You are very welcome to test, just remember the following:
>
> - Write down your seed and be always ready to use it to restore the identity.
> - **First thing you should do is get familiar with creating *and restoring* an identity**.
> - You can do: "create new identity", choose same name as before and restore, this will upgrade your store (you will still need to re add pockets and addresses, contacts etc...)
>
> If you notice strange behaviour after upgrading, you should:
>
> - Restart the background process from darkwallet (from "manage extensions")
> - If that doesn't work: Clear Darkwallet storage, (from darkwallet settings), restart chromium
>
> Remember: Your funds are safe as long as you don't lose your seed to restore later.
>
> Other than that **we're not making many guarantees.**

(my emphasis)

This project seems to have fizzled out a couple of years ago, so you may find it difficult to find anyone who is able and willing to help ... and honest.

See also

- [What is a stealth address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20701/13866)

Comment: Thank you for your time, i just need someone to help me write a script to get the private key from the stealth address or can do it for me and i will pay 50$ in btc.

Comment: @chicopee, don't put your seed/private key into software you don't understand. I'd only run it on a PC that will never be connected to a network.

Comment: so should i give you the seed and stealth address?

Comment: @chicopee: Don't give the seed to anyone, if you do, you are giving them all your Bitcoin. what I meant was if someone sends you software they created for you, before putting your seed into it, you need to be 100% certain that the software does not send your seed to a scam artist who will use it to steal your bitcoins. Create a new seed and stealth address with zero balance to use in testing any software sent to you. Also make sure you can read and understand what the source code does. By the way $50 is unlikely to get the attention of a software developer in a developed / western nation.

Comment: ok, so what do i do, no one has any clue on what stealth address is.